# Angular app log out after giving chrome camera/mic access on iOS

Tags: ios, angular, google-chrome

I have very strange problem. There is angular app which works so good on desktop, android, even Safari on iOS, but Chrome on iOS has strange behaviour. When I give Chrome permission to access camera or mic. My angular app is refreshing and logging out. When I refresh manually, it does not log out. Anybody has idea what is going on? Thanks